# Beamer infolines outer theme with miniframe bullets only for the current section

Tags: beamer, sectioning, navigation, mini-frames

I am wondering whether we can use the subsection part of the beamer `infolines` outer theme headline (the right half) to show the miniframe bullets of the current section. Assuming the section has three frames, the headline would look like this

First frame of the section:

```
       Section Title @oo
       Frame title
```

Next frame of the section:

```
       Section Title o@o
       Frame title
```

and so on.

I guess this can be done by hacking around `\dohead`, but I couldn't figure out how to tweak things. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing, a mix of the infolines and smoothbars. Did you find some solution?

Answer (score 11):

This is quite a hackish solution: It starts with the `miniframes` outer theme and patches the internal `beamer` commands in order to remove the other sections from the headline:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% "Beamer infolines outer theme with miniframe bullets only for the current section"
% (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45152/3323)
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in other section}{}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\let\beamer@section@set@min@width=\relax
\patchcmd{\insertnavigation}{\hskip-1.875ex plus-1fill}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\sectionentry}{\hskip1.875ex plus 1fill}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\sectionentry}{\hyperlink{Navigation#3}{{\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}}}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\slideentry}{\usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}}{\usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection of current section}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\slideentry}{\usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}}{\usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other section}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\slideentry}{\usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection of current section}}{\usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 1}}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 2}}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 3}}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 1}}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 2}}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 3}}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 4}}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 1}}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 2}}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 3}}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 4}}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 1}}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 2}}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 3}}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 4}}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 5}}
\end{document}
```

#### Example headline:

[image: example headline: section 2, subsection 1, frame 3]

(If you want to have all mini frames in one line instead of using a single line per subsection, you can use `\documentclass[compress]{beamer}` as usual.)

---

### Explanation of the code:

We use the outer theme `miniframes` and remove all the mini frames that do not belong to the current section:

```
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in other section}{}
```

Now, [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) is used to remove some code from the `beamer` macros responsible for generating the navigation bar:

- Remove the space between the sections:

  ```
  \let\beamer@section@set@min@width=\relax
  \patchcmd{\insertnavigation}{\hskip-1.875ex plus-1fill}{}{}{}
  \patchcmd{\sectionentry}{\hskip1.875ex plus 1fill}{}{}{}
  ```
- Do not display sections other than the current section at all:

  ```
  \patchcmd{\sectionentry}{\hyperlink{Navigation#3}{{\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}}}}{}{}{}
  ```
- Fix an inconsistency in the current `beamer` version: currently, the template `mini frame in other subsection` is used for both mini frames in the current section and other sections, where the latter case should use `mini frame in other section`:

  ```
  \patchcmd{\slideentry}{\usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}}{\usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection of current section}}{}{}
  \patchcmd{\slideentry}{\usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}}{\usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other section}}{}{}
  \patchcmd{\slideentry}{\usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection of current section}}{\usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}}{}{}
  ```

Comment: I really appreciate the explanation of the code! A further look-and-feel question: is it possible to center your navigation bar?

Comment: @diabonas Your solution works well, thank you! Is there a way to show all the circles at once instead of showing only the circles for current section?

Comment: @Mappi To do that, you can add `\patchcmd{\insertnavigation}{\hskip.3cm}{\hfill}{}{}\patchcmd{\insertnavigation}{\hskip.3cm}{\hfill}{}{}` (sic!) right before `\makeatother`.

Comment: @GeMir You mean the mini frames for the other subsection of the current section? I have updated the answer to do that.

Comment: @diabonas Thank you for your answer! I mean this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315234/beamer-changing-the-title-in-the-navigation-bar-dynamically

Comment: @GeMir Oh OK, I see, that should be possible, I will write up an answer shortly.