# Only one bullet per subsection in header

Tags: beamer, navigation, mini-frames

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [One navigation bullet per subsection with subsection=false in custom beamer theme](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64333/one-navigation-bullet-per-subsection-with-subsection-false-in-custom-beamer-them)

I want to have in my header of my presentation only one bullet for each subsection.
Although several questions handle similar problems, I was not able to solve my problem so far.

Here is to code I use:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Singapore} 

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty 

\begin{document}
\section{Text1}
\subsection{Text1.1}
\frame{Text1.1.1}
\frame{Text1.1.2}
\frame{Text1.1.3}
\subsection{Text1.2}
\frame{Text1.2.1}
\frame{Text1.2.2}
\subsection{Text1.3}
\frame{Text1.3.1}
\section{Text2}
\subsection{Text2.1}
\frame{Text2.1.1}
\frame{Text2.1.2}
\frame{Text2.1.3}
\subsection{Text2.2}
\frame{Text2.2.1}
\frame{Text2.2.2}
\subsection{Text2.3}
\frame{Text2.3.1}
\frame{Text2.3.2}
\frame{Text2.3.3}
\end{document}
```

At the moment I get for each slide in a subsection a bullet. What do I have to change so that I get only one bullet for each subsection?
I would be very happy about some help!

Answer (score 1):

I oversaw that [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64333/one-navigation-bullet-per-subsection-with-subsection-false-in-custom-beamer-them) a very nice solution is given which works very well for me. 
Unfortunately, I oversaw this solution because of the long title of the question.
I hope that other people with a similar problem will find to this answer, either directly or via my question.