# beamer class - messing with the navigation bar

Tags: beamer, numbering, navigation

I want to have just one dot in the navigation bar for every subsection, and not for every frame.

And I want to have the page numbering displayed in the top (inside the second blue stripe of the heading rightsided).

Grateful for help. Here my small example.
(Here the result should have 3 dots and the page numbering should be inside the blue bar under Section 2)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,compress]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usetheme{Berlin}

\author{John Gerick}
\title{My Stuff}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents[sections={1}]
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
\begin{frame}
  first frame of 1.1
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  second frame of 1.1
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 1.2}
\begin{frame}
  first frame of 1.2
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  second frame of 1.2
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  third frame of 1.2
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents[sections={2}]
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 2.1}
\begin{frame}
  first frame of 2.1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  second frame of 2.1
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: Unrelated to your question: you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` with beamer

Comment: Ok, I removed that package. I still need some control over the navigation bar.

Comment: In case you have happen to have an old enough version of beamer you could try https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64333/one-navigation-bullet-per-subsection-with-subsection-false-in-custom-beamer-them, but in won't give the correct result with the current beamer version

Answer (score 2):

For the second part of your question, you could redefine the headline as the following to include the frame numbers:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,compress]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usetheme{Berlin}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertframenumber\quad\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

\author{John Gerick}
\title{My Stuff}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents[sections={1}]
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
\begin{frame}
  first frame of 1.1
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  second frame of 1.1
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 1.2}
\begin{frame}
  first frame of 1.2
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  second frame of 1.2
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  third frame of 1.2
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents[sections={2}]
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 2.1}
\begin{frame}
  first frame of 2.1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  second frame of 2.1
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thx a lot. This was what I needed. I slightly changed the order though. \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead \hspace*{\fill} \insertframenumber / \inserttotalframenumber

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution pretty close to what I was locking for here on 
[this Page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37127/how-to-remove-some-pages-from-the-navigation-bullets-in-beamer). This works after fixing the [package conflict](https://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/1444/latex-error-option-clash-for-package-wie-beheben).
By now changing the **\defbeamertemplate*{mini frame in current subsection}{Berlin}** as can be seen below I achieved exacly what I wanted. Now I have one bullet for each subsection and no matter what pdf viewer is used, you get to the first frame of the subsection if you klick on a bullet.

For total control of Navigation points you now need to start a subsection with frame for each bullet you want to add.

The fixed code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,compress]{beamer}
\PassOptionsToPackage{subsection=false}{useoutertheme{miniframes}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usetheme{Berlin}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead \hspace*{\fill} \insertframenumber / \inserttotalframenumber
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\let\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson=\beamer@writeslidentry
\def\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff{%
  \expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@framestartpage}{}% does not happen normally
  {%else
    % removed \addtocontents commands
    \clearpage\beamer@notesactions%
  }
}
\newcommand*{\miniframeson}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson}
\newcommand*{\miniframesoff}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff}
\makeatother

\defbeamertemplate*{mini frame in current subsection}{Berlin}
{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{0.1cm}{0.1cm}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0.05cm}{0.05cm}}{0.05cm}
    \pgfusepath{fill,stroke}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}

\author{John Gerick} \title{My Stuff}

\begin{document}
\miniframesoff

\begin{frame} \titlepage\end{frame}

\begin{frame} \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections] \end{frame}

\section{Section 1} \begin{frame} \tableofcontents[sections={1}] \end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
\miniframeson
\begin{frame} first frame of 1.1 \end{frame}
\miniframesoff
\begin{frame} second frame of 1.1 \end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 1.2}
\miniframeson
\begin{frame} first frame of 1.2 \end{frame}
\miniframesoff
\begin{frame} second frame of 1.2 \end{frame}
\begin{frame} third frame of 1.2 \end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame} \tableofcontents[sections={2}] \end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 2.1}
\miniframeson
\begin{frame} first frame of 2.1 \end{frame}

\begin{frame} second frame of 2.1 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this Webpage. It helped me a lot to find the solution I needed.