# How to create mini sections, mini subsections and mini frames in beamer presentation mode

Tags: beamer, presentations, navigation, mini-frames

In my pretty long presentation, I am attempting to write a beamer theme with sections, subsections and frames navigational bullets as in picture below
[image: mini sections, mini subsections and mini frames navigational bullets]

I find out that there is no build-in theme meets my need. So how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

There are probably much better ways to do this, but instead of messing with beamer navigation I wanted to try something new and play with the `xcntperchap` package.

## Remarks:

- requires two compilations
- does not provide clickable links

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{section}

\usepackage{xcntperchap}
\RegisterCounters{section}{subsection}

\newcounter{totalsubsection}
\setcounter{totalsubsection}{0}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\preto\frame{\setcounter{totalsubsection}{\ObtainTrackedValueExp[\value{section}]{section}{subsection}}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcount\beamer@sectionstartframe
\beamer@sectionstartframe=1
\apptocmd{\beamer@section}{\addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{%
            \protect\beamer@sectionframes{\the\beamer@sectionstartframe}{\the\c@framenumber}}}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\beamer@section}{\beamer@sectionstartframe=\c@framenumber\advance\beamer@sectionstartframe by1\relax}{}{}
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{nav}%
        {\noexpand\headcommand{\noexpand\beamer@sectionframes{\the\beamer@sectionstartframe}{\the\c@framenumber}}}}}{}{}
\def\beamer@startframeofsection{1}
\def\beamer@endframeofsection{1}
\def\beamer@sectionframes#1#2{%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber<#1%
    \else%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber>#2%
    \else%
    \gdef\beamer@startframeofsection{#1}%
    \gdef\beamer@endframeofsection{#2}%
    \fi%
    \fi%
}
\newcommand\insertsectionstartframe{\beamer@startframeofsection}
\newcommand\insertsectionendframe{\beamer@endframeofsection}
\makeatother

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\def\inserttotalsectionframenumber{%
    \pgfmathparse{(\insertsectionendframe-\insertsectionstartframe+1)}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}%
}

\def\insertsectionframenumber{%
    \pgfmathparse{(\insertframenumber-\insertsectionstartframe+1)}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}%
}

\newcounter{sectionframenumber}
\newcounter{totalsectionframenumber}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \vskip1em%
    \hbox{%  
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex]{section in head/foot}%
            \centering%
            \insertsection\par%
            \vskip0.2em%
            \foreach\x in {1,...,\totvalue{section}}{%
                \ifnum\x=\value{section}%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame}~%
                \else%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other section}~%
                \fi%
            }%
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex]{subsection in head/foot}%
            \ifnum\value{totalsubsection}>0%
            \centering%
            \insertsubsection\par%
            \vskip0.2em%
            \foreach\x in {1,...,\value{totalsubsection}}{%
                \ifnum\x=\value{subsection}%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame}~%
                \else%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}~%
                \fi%
            }%
            \fi%
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex]{section in head/foot}%
            \centering%
            \ifx\insertframetitle\empty\else%
                \insertframetitle\par%
            \fi%
            \vskip0.2em%
            \setcounter{sectionframenumber}{1}
            \addtocounter{sectionframenumber}{\insertframenumber}
            \addtocounter{sectionframenumber}{-\insertsectionstartframe}
            \setcounter{totalsectionframenumber}{1}
            \addtocounter{totalsectionframenumber}{\insertsectionendframe}
            \addtocounter{totalsectionframenumber}{-\insertsectionstartframe}
            \foreach\x in {1,...,\value{totalsectionframenumber}}{%
                \ifnum\x=\value{sectionframenumber}%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame}~%
                \else%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}~%
                \fi%
            }%
        \end{beamercolorbox}%       
    }}

    \def\insertframetitle{}

    \begin{document}    
        \section{Section1}
        \subsection{Subsection1}
        \begin{frame}
            \frametitle{Frame11}
        \end{frame}

        \subsection{Subsection2}
        \begin{frame}
            \frametitle{Frame12}
        \end{frame}

        \section{Section2}
        \begin{frame}
            \frametitle{Frame2}
        \end{frame}

        \subsection{Subsection1}
        \begin{frame}
            \frametitle{Frame21}
        \end{frame}

        \subsection{Subsection2}
        \begin{frame}
            \frametitle{Frame22}
        \end{frame}

        \subsection{Subsection3}
        \begin{frame}
            \frametitle{Frame23}
        \end{frame}

        \section{Section3}
        \begin{frame}
            \frametitle{Frame3}
        \end{frame}

        \frame{}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Pretty great! But I prefer a clickable link. It is easy to navigate to the frame I want.

Comment: @SayOL If you want clickable, maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23151/beamer-infolines-outer-theme-with-miniframe-bullets-only-for-the-current-section and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315234/beamer-changing-the-title-in-the-navigation-bar-dynamically are starting points you can modify.

Comment: it seems to be complicated.

Comment: @SayOL Yes! You see why I used the easy road?