# Beamer — changing the title in the navigation bar dynamically

Tags: beamer, navigation, mini-frames, frame-title

Is there a way to change the title of the entire presentation in the navigation bar dynamically?

Now:

[image]

Needed:

[image]

All 6 of 6 circles should be shown in navigation bar, not only 3 of 6 for current section!

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false, shadow]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{default}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\setbeamerfont{title like}{shape=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{shape=\scshape}
\setbeamercolor*{lower separation line head}{bg=black!10} 
\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=black, bg=white} 
\setbeamercolor*{alerted text}{fg=red} 
\setbeamercolor*{example text}{fg=black} 
\setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=black} 
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{fg=black, bg=black!5} 
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=black, bg=black!5} 

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\begin{document}

% The miniframe circles should not be splitted in two groups (if possible)

\section*{Title 1} % <-- Only this title should be visible in the first section
\subsection*{}

\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\section*{Title 2} % <-- ...and only this title in the second section
\subsection*{}

\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The simple way to do so is probably to set the title of the presentation equal to subsection title — is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Beamer infolines outer theme with miniframe bullets only for the current section](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23151/beamer-infolines-outer-theme-with-miniframe-bullets-only-for-the-current-section)

Comment: @samcarter Yes, it almost is. But as you can see I need all (6 of 6 in my example) circles at once and the solution by diabonas shows only the circles for current section (3 of 6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code somewhere between `\documentclass{beamer}` and `\begin{document}`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\beamer@compresstrue
\patchcmd{\insertnavigation}{\hskip-1.875ex plus-1fill}{}{}{}
\apptocmd{\partentry}{\beamer@xpos=0\relax}{}{}
\def\sectionentry#1#2#3#4#5{% section number, section title, page
  \ifnum#5=\c@part%
  \hbox{\def\insertsectionhead{#2}%
    \def\insertsectionheadnumber{#1}%
    \def\insertpartheadnumber{#5}%
    {%
      \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
      \ifnum\c@section=#1%
        \rlap{\hyperlink{Navigation#3}{{\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot}}}}%
      \fi}%
  }%
  \fi\ignorespaces}
\makeatother
```

[image: headline for the example document, with all six mini frames shown]

The tricks used to get all the mini frames while displaying only the current section title are similar to what was used in [Beamer infolines outer theme with miniframe bullets only for the current section:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23151/3323)

- For simplicity, all mini frames are displayed in one line using the `compress` option:

  ```
  \beamer@compresstrue
  ```
- Remove the filling space to left align the navigation bar:

  ```
  \patchcmd{\insertnavigation}{\hskip-1.875ex plus-1fill}{}{}{}
  ```
- Reset the mini frames position at the start of each part, as this will not be done at the beginning of each section any more to create a continuous line of mini frames:

  ```
  \apptocmd{\partentry}{\beamer@xpos=0\relax}{}{}
  ```
- Rewrite the `\sectionentry` macro to not reset the mini frames position and to only show the current section title. The important thing here is to wrap the title in `\rlap` so that it does not take up any space, otherwise there would be a gap in the line of mini frames:

  ```
  \def\sectionentry#1#2#3#4#5{...}
  ```