# Beamer theme customization: modifying frankfurt

Tags: beamer, presentations

I personally like the Beamer theme `Frankfurt', however for longer presentations with a lot of slides/sections I'm finding that the header space where the sections and the slide dots are listed is not large enough.

My preference would be that rather than listing all sections, the header space only showed the *current* section plus the navigation dots, either left-justified or centered.

Here is a MWE of what you get by default:

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Frankfurt}}

\title{The title}
\author{A name}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}{stuff}
some stuff
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{stuff}
some stuff
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}{stuff}
some stuff
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{stuff}
some stuff
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You can see in the MWE result that both section 1 and 2 are listed in the header for all slides.

I don't know the first thing about modifying beamer layouts - anyone have advice? thanks!

Comment: Is this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315234/beamer-changing-the-title-in-the-navigation-bar-dynamically what you want?

Comment: @samcarter looks like it! I'll try it now. I did look through older questions before posting but missed this. Thanks!

Comment: @samcarter That question isn't precisely it, however in the question you linked you also mentioned [this thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23151/beamer-infolines-outer-theme-with-miniframe-bullets-only-for-the-current-section) and that has exactly the solution I was looking for - so thanks!