# comparing \x and \value{section} with if

Tags: conditionals

I want to evaluate whether my variable \x (that comes from a foreach loop) is the same as my current section number.
I tried

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{totcount}       
\regtotcounter{section}             % total amount of sections

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \section{This is the first section} \label{sec:this_is_the_first_section}
        Some Text.
  \section{This is the second section} \label{sec:this_is_the_second_section}
        Some Text.
  \section{This is the third section} \label{sec:this_is_the_third_section}
        Some Text.

  \foreach \x in {1,...,\totvalue{section}}{
    \arabic{section} =  \x
      \ifx\x\value{section}
        check
      \else
        no                          
      \fi}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

but this always returns a "no" where in the last case it should return a "check". Do I have to use a different form of the "if"-case (i tried

```
   \ifnum{\value{\x}}={\value{section}}
```

but that didnt even compile) or am I trying to compare different variable types that can't be compared like that?
What would be the correct commandline to compare the values?

Comment: ``\ifnum\x=\value{section} ``  is more correct (with a space at the end). (Note this doesn't answer any part of the question, it's just a suggestion.)

Comment: I would simply do `\ifnum\x=\thesection`, works fine with beamer, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313579/36296 for an application.

Comment: @Manuel there is no need for space at end, because `\value{section}` gives a TeX count register. So the space token is not swallowed by the `\ifnum` test and depending on context may actually show in output.

Comment: @samcarter: `\thesection` can expand to something like `A` or `A.2` etc. In this case `\ifnum` would be useless with `\thesection`. Don't trust `\the...` macros expanding to literal numbers

Comment: @Manuel I think that's exactly the answer to both parts of the question:-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer All standard beamer themes use numerical representations - so one normally gets away with this ...

Comment: @samcarter... for standard ones yes... I don't trust it, however

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If it's true, please, confirm. I really did not read the question :)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Somewhere the supply of new questions for the counter wizard has to come from :)

Comment: @samcarter: Yes, but there's nothing to answer for me here ... it has been answered already in comments.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I prefer not to answer, I really did not read the question. You can answer yourself; or may be jfbu (who corrected me).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Not in this questions, but with my careless usage of `\the...` it will break somewhere for someone and the user will come back to this site and ask a questions you can answer.

Comment: @Manuel thx, your suggestion was the solution to my proplem. So, '\ifnum\x=\value{section} ' did the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using `\ifnum` correctly. It might work, but depending on the situation, it might not work. The correct usage is

```
\ifnum\x=\value{section}
```

that way the first number `\x` is delimited by the `=` and the second number `\value{section}` doesn't need to be delimited because it gets an internal TeX count.

Comment: Thx, that did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from different programming languages to TeX can be a tough experience, because conditionals in TeX are a bit weird.

If you want to compare two integers, the conditional to use is `\ifnum` that wants a syntax

```
\ifnum<integer><relation><integer>
```

*without* braces around the integers, so your test should be

```
\ifnum\x=\value{section}
```

(don't forget a trailing `%` if you don't want a space from the newline character).

Note that `\value` is not a general purpose ”extractor“, but a very specific LaTeX macro which only works if its argument is a LaTeX counter defined with `\newcounter`, whose expansion is the ”abstract” value.

Similarly, `\arabic` is a LaTeX macro for accessing the decimal representation of the counter; it *might* be used here, but not recommended for several reasons (termination of the `<integer>` specification is the main one).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{section}             % total amount of sections

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\section{This is the first section} \label{sec:this_is_the_first_section}
Some Text.

\section{This is the second section} \label{sec:this_is_the_second_section}

Some Text.

\section{This is the third section} \label{sec:this_is_the_third_section}
Some Text.

\foreach \x in {1,...,\totvalue{section}}{%
  \ifnum\x=\value{section}%
    check
  \else
    no
  \fi
}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note the `%` I added; the lines with `check` and `no` will add a space, because the end-of-line is not masked off. The last space will vanish as it's at the end of a paragraph.

[image]