# Beamer: Split up Miniframes into two parts

Tags: beamer, navigation, mini-frames

I have far too many elements in my navigation bar because the slides are a summary of an entire course.
[image]

Is there a way to split up the navigation bar's miniframes such that shows the first half until slide x and from slide x, the second part?
Is there a smart way to do this?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45152/133968: to show only the miniframe for the current section. May give you an idea to try something similar.